# Finding shared data in multiple columns

Tags: sql

Here's my table "Earth"

[image: http://imgur.com/EIlbKEN]

I need to find all records / rows, in which people share

- the same Country
- and within this same Country, they need to share the same State
- and within this same State, they need to share the same City

In this query, I can't use any specific country, state, or city names.  Therefore is there a query I can use, that will still return for example two or more people who share the same country, state, and city?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a self join.  It would look something like this:

```
select t1.personid, t2.personid, t1.country, t1.state, t1.city
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.country = t2.country and t1.state = t2.state and t1.city = t2.city and
        t1.personid < t2.personid;
```